# Getting an 500 Internal Server Error (ActiveRecord) while iterating over posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

i've an 500 error while iterating over differents posts of my db in my index layout page.

Here is the log :

```
Started GET "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-07-18 22:23:44 +0200
Processing by PostsController#index as HTML
  Rendering posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Post Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"
  ↳ app/views/posts/index.html.erb:14
  Rendered posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 1923.6ms | Allocations: 18335)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7372ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms | Allocations: 37272)
```

Here is the controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
    def index
        @posts = Post.all
        respond_to do |format|
         format.html  # index.html.erb
         format.json  { render json: @posts }
        end
    end
  def show; end

  def new
      @post = Post.new(post_params)     
      if @post.save
         redirect_to @post, notice: "The post was created!"
      else 
         render ‘new’
      end 
   end
  
  def create
      @post = Post.new(post_params)     
      if @post.save
          redirect_to @post, notice: "The post was created!"
      else 
          render ‘new’
      end 
  end

  def edit; end

  def update
      if @post.update(post_params)
          redirect_to @post, notice: "Update successful"
      else
          render ‘edit’
      end
  end

 def destroy
     @post.destroy
     redirect_to root_path, notice: "Post destroyed"
 end



private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :category_id)
end

def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])        
end
end
```

Here is my db entry for my posts:

[image: my post]

Here is my index view page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Blog</title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
   <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>

  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
     <h1><%= link_to "post.title", post.title %></h1>
     <p><%= post.content %></p>
  <% end %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Note that i'm beginning into ruby (just for personal purpose).

Thanks in advance, don't hesitate to ask me question or ressources if needed

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. As you are just learning may I make a suggestion that you start with the latest version of Rails. Rails 4 is very outdated and the latest version is 6.. Could you please include your `index.html.erb` code inside code tag in your actual question please

Comment: I would have expected a much more detailed error log than just a 500 error message, however I can see what is wrong with your view but I need to see the controller action that renders the view as well, so could you please post that inside your question in a code tag along with the view code, it will make it so muich easier for people to answer your question

Comment: thanks the welcoming and for your fast response.
My apologyze i mentionned rby version 4 on the thread but i've the latest version of ruby (or quite) (6.0.0).

Comment: Yeah not easy to debug and i'm newbie to this language btw so ... ><

i edit my question for the details you asked me

Comment: As soon as I can see your code I'll be able to answer your question

Comment: I can see you are struggling with code tags, remove the triple back ticks, highlight thew code and hit the curly braces button in the editor. I'd open up a chat room to help but you don't have enough reputation yet to be able to join in and don't forget to post up the index.html.erb view. What resource are you using to learn?

Comment: yeah finally succeded ahaha thanks :d

To learn ruby either official documentation or tutorialspoint site (and stack of course)

Comment: the index.html.erb is already there yeah

Comment: Nope. You need to post the code into your question an external image link is not at all helpful, I can't copy and paste your code

Comment: ok of course i do that so

Comment: finally put the entire code to debug easily and be 'iso'
but i miss some indentations btw by editing sry

Comment: Does your code really have `render ‘new’` and `render ‘edit’` or is it `render 'new'` and `render 'edit'`? Note the different quotes.

Comment: your right!! problem resolved :)
it was the quotes (not in the controller but in the "application.html.erb")

i had <%= render ‘shared/nav’ %>
instead of "<%= render 'shared/nav' %>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your controller code needs tidying up a little. Looks like you are coming from maybe a java background, you need to get rid of those `;`

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_post, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
    def index
        @posts = Post.all
        respond_to do |format|
         format.html  # index.html.erb
         format.json  { render json: @posts }
        end
    end

def show
end

def new
  @post = Post.new(post_params)     
  if @post.save
     redirect_to @post, notice: "The post was created!"
  else 
     render 'new'
  end 
end
  
def create
  @post = Post.new(post_params)     
  if @post.save
      redirect_to @post, notice: "The post was created!"
  else 
      render 'new'
  end 
end

def edit
end

def update
  if @post.update(post_params)
      redirect_to @post, notice: "Update successful"
  else
      render 'edit'
  end

  end

  def destroy
     @post.destroy
     redirect_to root_path, notice: "Post destroyed"
  end

private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :category_id)
  end

  def find_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])        
  end

end
```

The `%i` syntax on your before action is also a little alien to me. I would normally expect it to use symbols

```
before_action :find_post, only: [:show :edit :update :destroy]
```

However, the main issue is with your view

In your views folder there should be a layout folder. Inside that you should have an application.html.erb template. The doctype, head and body section should be in there. This is not the cause of your error though.

Your `PostsController` inherits from `ApplicationController` which sets the name of the layout to be used, this can be overriden with a layout directive on a per controller basis if you wish

In your layout you should have a `yield` statement inside the `body` tag and this magically pops the content of whatever view template is being rendered, this is the perfect place to render headers and footers so you only ever have one header view partial and one footer view partial that gets rendered with every page. Hope that makes sense.

So your template should really only contain the code specific to the view that is being rendered

```
  <% @posts.each do |post| %>
     <h1><%= link_to "post.title", post.title %></h1>
     <p><%= post.content %></p>
  <% end %>
```

The error is an error in the link for the post title

```
 <h1><%= link_to "post.title", post.title %></h1>
```

The `link_to` helper takes as it's first parameter a string value for the text that will be shown which in your case is the text `post.title` so you should change that to show the actual title of the post which in your case is fsdfsd to do that use `post.title` to get the value from the field

So you now have

```
<h1><%= link_to post.title %></h1>
```

But you are missing the url to link to which I am guessing should be the show action of the actual post record right?
To get that you can just use the instance variable and rails will extract the path from, which in this case is the `post` obect it so you end up with

```
<h1><%= link_to post.title, post %></h1>
```

oh, and change the quiotes on the render statements in your controller as suggested by others

//Edit1: Just changed ’ quotes to ' quotes for 'new' function

Comment: you're right but seems like when you define empty method (all on the same line) you need to put them apparently

Comment: Possibly, it's not something I have ever done so I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: @Handler, I have updated my answer with some clarity on how to structure your view templates. I can add more detail on how the layout side of things works if you wish. You might want to take a look at the old railscasts by Ryan Bates for some inspiration, the code is very out of date but the videos are still a superb resource and still very relevant. If you want to get serious then AWDWR book from pragprog.com is the Rails bible along with programming ruby which is the eqivalent ruby bible. Feel free to give my answer a vote and accept when you can

Comment: thanks quotes resolved my problem (on rendering the layout "application.html.erb") i will give a glance at that.

And thanks to @mu_is_too_short

Comment: @Handler, yeah, I missed that, but the link_to was wrong and you have layout code in your view template

Comment: yeah i haven't post it so it's my bad. thanks all :)